# Assign token to logged in user in Xamarin.Forms PCL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I have an application using PCL that allows users to use the app once they've logged in via facebook. I've done much research but haven't found a way to assign each logged in user with a unique token and then save user to database using a webApi. This token will be the primary key to identifying user-specific details in the app. Any help on how to go about doing this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Below is my FacebookRender class in the Droid

```
namespace LoyaltyWorx.Droid
{
    public class FacebookRender : PageRenderer
    {
        public FacebookRender()
        {
            var activity = this.Context as Activity;

            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                clientId: //my app's client id,
                scope: "",
                authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
                redirectUrl: new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html")
                );

            auth.Completed += async (sender, eventArgs) =>
                {
                    if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        var accessToken = eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"].ToString();
                        var expiresIn = Convert.ToDouble(eventArgs.Account.Properties["expires_in"]);
                        var expiryDate = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(expiresIn);

                        var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me"), null, eventArgs.Account);
                        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                        var obj = JObject.Parse(response.GetResponseText());

                        var id = obj["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                        var name = obj["name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");

                        App.NavigateToProfile(string.Format(name));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        App.NavigateToProfile("Invalid Login");
                    }
                };
            activity.StartActivity(auth.GetUI(activity));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the Xamarin.Auth plugin, which means you can use their API to save the token in the native secure storage on the device.

```
if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated) {

    /* Just save the whole account here, you can also add custom properties to it if you want */
    await AccountStore.Create().SaveAsync(eventArgs.Account, "FacebookProviderKey");




    var accessToken = eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"].ToString();
    var expiresIn = Convert.ToDouble(eventArgs.Account.Properties["expires_in"]);
    var expiryDate = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(expiresIn);

    var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me"), null, eventArgs.Account);
    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    var obj = JObject.Parse(response.GetResponseText());

    var id = obj["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
    var name = obj["name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");

    App.NavigateToProfile(string.Format(name));
}
```

*Edit: To store the data in your DB, you would just need to make a REST call to your Web API endpoint. You could use `HttpClient` from your mobile app to make that rest call like so:

```
public async Task SendData(Account accountInfo) {

    HttpContent content = new StringContent(await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(accountInfo), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)); //Turn your Account data into a string to be sent to Web API
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");  //Tell what kind of string it is, it is JSON in this case

    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://someurl.com/Where/Web/Api/Lives") {
            Content = content
    };  //Change the URL to your Web API URL, add data, and set as POST request

    using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    using(HttpResponseMessage message = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).Token).ConfigureAwait(false)) { //Send the actual message

        if(message.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            //Celebrate your success!
        } else {
            //You failed, sucks to suck
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to save the token along with user's name and email to my database though, I have an existing webApi so how can I store the user to my database. Sorry I know this is asking for too much, but I am very new to Xamarin and WebApi's. Just a link to where I should look to accomplish this will be fine. I researched a lot but couldn't find a way to do this.

Comment: thank you! I have tried this but it's not inserting into my database. :(. Where are you getting cancellationToken from ? Is it fine to leave it out

Comment: @Unicorn_Girl It depends on how your Web API endpoint is setup to take in the data. Also yes, you can leave that out.

Answer (score 0):

Storing `access_token` is considered bad security practice. Better practice is to store `refresh_token`, but using AccountStore in Xamarin.Auth is possible.